# InfusionSoft: API error While Fetching contact Details

Tags: php, php-curl, infusionsoft

I'm working on InfusionSoft API ([documentation here](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-retrieve-a-contact)) and making request by using CURL (no API SDK) but getting the following error.

`Failed to parse XML-RPC request: Premature end of file.`

any help would be appreciated. Below is the CURL code that I'm using.

```
$url_token = 'http://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/xmlrpc/v1/?access_token='.$access_token;

$curlPost = array(
                'access_token' => $access_token,
                'privateKey' => $api_key,
                'contactId' => 6171,
                'selectedFields' => array('email')
            );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curlPost));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
echo $res;
```

Comment: The API seems to be an XML API and you're passing it JSON.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question...

Comment: There is already documentation, with code examples for their PHP library.  Does that help? https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#authentication-request-an-access-token